# how to get ordispider-like clusters in ggplot with nmds?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, vegan

I have just successfully managed to plot and ordisurf model on top of my non-metric multi dimensional scale plot. 
Code was used from this site. 
https://oliviarata.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/ordinations-in-ggplot2-v2-ordisurf/

However my problem is that I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to plot cluster graphics using ggplot. I've looked around and the closest I came to was this:
[R - add centroids to scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463324/r-add-centroids-to-scatter-plot)

Where the answer involved creating centroids and extending lines from it to points but this was not done with a nmds object so I'm still puzzled.

I used vegan to run my nmds and gpplot for plotting. 
I would add my data but it's composed of two very large community and environment datasets. The nmds and the subsequent ordisurf function requires the full data to run.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample input data and the code you've already tried. Describe exactly where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I'm not able to because subsetting the data would result in a different mds object and therefore a completely different nmds. The environmental data would also be needed. I already tried attaching the dput() version of the dataframes and couldn't even fit the first one in due to a character limit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, which should make its way into my **ggvegan** package at some point.

```
library('vegan')
library('ggplot2')
```

For this example I'm going to use the Dutch dune meadow data set tha ships with vegan

```
data(dune, dune.env)
```

and I'll use the `Management` variable in `dune.env` as my cluster membership vector. Notice it is coded as a factor; you should ensure that whatever cluster membership vector you use is coded likewise.

First the example ordination

```
ord <- metaMDS(dune)
```

Next, extract the NMDS scores

```
scrs <- scores(ord, display = 'sites')
```

To facilitate computing centroids, I add `Management` as a variable to the data frame of scores

```
scrs <- cbind(as.data.frame(scrs), Management = dune.env$Management)
```

Now we compute the group centroids, which are the mean coordinate on each axis, groupwise:

```
cent <- aggregate(cbind(NMDS1, NMDS2) ~ Management, data = scrs, FUN = mean)
```

To draw the spider, we need to us `geom_segment()` which requires coordiates to draw the segment *from* and *to*. Our *to* coordinates, the `xend` and `yend` aesthetics will be the centroids. So we need to replicate the group centroid for each observation in the group. This we facilitate by a left join via `merge`:

```
segs <- merge(scrs, setNames(cent, c('Management','oNMDS1','oNMDS2')),
              by = 'Management', sort = FALSE)
```

notice that I rename the columns in `cent` so these do't get confused for columns of the same names in `scrs` — we want these centroid variables to have different names.

Now we can plot

```
ggplot(scrs, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, colour = Management)) +
  geom_segment(data = segs,
               mapping = aes(xend = oNMDS1, yend = oNMDS2)) + # spiders
  geom_point(data = cent, size = 5) +                         # centroids
  geom_point() +                                              # sample scores
  coord_fixed()                                               # same axis scaling
```

Which produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gg_envfit function in the GitHub package ggordiplots (https://github.com/jfq3/ggordiplots). There are links to  the package documentation and vignettes on the GitHub page of john-quensen.com. All functions in the package silently return data frames you may use to make your own plot modifications. A vignette for doing so is included.